# Hiding a model field in Django admin 1.9

Tags: django, django-admin

I have registered some models to display in the admin area, but I would like for some fields to be hidden.

As an example, I have a TeachingClasses model with a BooleanField named 'Status' that is set to True or False depending if the class is open or not.  But that is set somewhere else in the app.  There is no need to have that field displayed in the admin area when someone wants to create a new class to attend.

As such, is there a way to hide that field in the admin area?

I have tried adding this to the app admin.py file but it did nothing

```
from django.contrib import admin

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class TeachingClasses:
        exclude = ('Status',)
```

but it's not working?

Any clue if this is the right way?

My model:

```
class TeachingClasses(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield('Class Name',max_lenght=64)
    [...]
    status = models.BooleanField('Status',default=True)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you did is not the correct syntax, you need:

```
class TeachingClassesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('status',)

admin.site.register(TeachingClasses, TeachingClassesAdmin)
```

[Django doc about how to use exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude).

Comment: Make sure you register the class with the admin as well.

Comment: This is a lot easier :)

Comment: This worked beautifully, thanks!  And thanks for the link in the doc.  Programming is a hobby here(working in IT) and docs are often more confusing than not to me.  As such, I completely missed this when I browsed the doc earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In the admin.py:

```
class TeachingClassesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)  # plus any other fields you'd like to display 
admin.site.register(TeachingClasses, TeachingClassesAdmin)`
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what OP wants - they want to hide a field, not modify the `list_display`